# Large arrays in Julia

Tags: bigdata, julia

I have a 10000x10000 array in Julia, say `A=rand(10000,10000)`. How can I store that large array so I can work with it in a IDE like Atom/Juno, performing matrices operations, determinants, eigenvalues and so on? Or even if I transfer that array to `R`, is it a way to work with that large array in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sparse (not all cells have values) you can store it as a sparse Matrix, which will greatly improve the memory footprint (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/). Whether or not it fits into memory also depends on what the elements of the Matrix are. E.g. can you represent the values with Int8 or do you need 64-bit precision elements? A Matrix is not just a Matrix.

On a more general note, if your objects become so big they don't fit into memory, you can write them to disk and "memory-map" them, in that way you can use on-disk Matrices for anything you can use a normal Matrix for. You can check the documentation here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap

Comment: Yes :-) I know the SparseArrays package for sparse matrices :-) my problem is more with dense matrices. But thank you for the documentation for the memory-mapping! Very helpful!